# Cocos2dx C++ Sending game data to a MySQL database on a remote server

Tags: php, android, c++, mysql, windows-phone-8

Creating a game for Android/Win32/WP8 using Cocos2dx written in C++.

I want to send basic game statistics to a remote MySQL database so they can be viewed on a webpage.

What I think will work:

- From the game on Android/Win32 use the cocos2dx network libraries to send a HTTP POST request to the remote server with the data from the game.
- On the server have MySQL database setup, use a PHP script to read the HTTP POST data from the game and store it in the database.
- Display the information to a webpage

I don't need to read data from the database to send it back to the game just yet so its just sending and storing the data that I'm interested in, then reading it to be displayed as a webpage I can connect to.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone else looking to do the same thing.

- I installed XAMPP to set up a server that runs locally at http://localhost.
- I then created a PHP script that read a *$_POST['username']* array variable to extract all of the key/value pairs from the HTTP POST from the game.
- From the Cocos2dx game I used the HTTPClient library to created a HTTP Request
- The Request data contained a string with a key/value pair so that the PHP script could read it on the server.
- The string looked like this:

  ```
  'username=damorton&score=playerScore'
  ```
- Send the request from the game using request->send(data); and specify http://localhost as the target.
- The PHP script can then identify the keys *username* and *score* by referencing its name in the array variable :

  ```
  $name = $_POST['username']
  $score = $_POST['score']
  ```

From here I just connected to a local MySQL database that I set up in XAMPP. Create some SQL queries in the PHP scripts for reading and writing the values stored in $name and $score. All communication with the database happens in the PHP scripts. The game interfaces with the PHP on the server to read and write to the database. And that was it.

I have since moved the local server to a remote one by copying the PHP scripts and using the domain name to access the PHP scripts.

```
    http://www.insertyourdomainnamehere.com/update_database.php
```

The game now uses an online leaderboard, is available on the Windows Store, and will update all of the players stats remotely.

Hope this helps someone out :)

Comment: Hey do you mind sending me your source code for reading and writing to database? Much appreciated

Comment: If you want to prevent people from calling the post themselves with a super high hiscore, you could add a third parameter (for example $checksum) and add some kind of encryption key of name+score that results in a checksum. You perfrom the same encryption in php and check if the checksum matches.